# How to properly use v-if and v-else in Vue JS <td> table tags

Tags: vue.js, html-table

Since my searches doesn't suffice my issue, I'm posting it here to have some clarification on how to properly use `v-if` and `v-else` in `<td>` tags in HTML table in Vue.

```
//given the value of this.property is name
<tr>
    <td v-if="this.property == 'name'">I'm name</td>
    <td v-else>No I'm not</td>
</tr>
```

And my problem is, even though my `this.property` value is `'name'` or **NOT** a `'name'` it always falls to the `v-else` condition, and `v-if` is not executed. The output I want is to execute the `v-if` if the `this.property` value is `'name'` and `v-else` if not.

Am I doing it the right way? I need your guidance here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove `this` pointer. You don't need it.

```
//given the value of this.property is name
<tr>
    <td v-if="property === 'name'">I'm name</td>
    <td v-else>No I'm not</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: God! I'm trapped with that one. Thought I have to use `this` since its a data property. And just a bit curious, why is pointer not needed?